# How to watch/poll a shared directory in windows/linux using java

Tags: java, polling, filesystemwatcher

How can I watch the the operations happening on a shared folder using java. I have to specify the `smb` path of the folder as an argument. I have tried with `Apache vfs`, java `WatchService` and `Jnotify` libraries. But non of these works on a smb url like `smb://share/mytestshare/`. Please help me to find any libraries that can used to poll shared smb folders.

Comment: Mount the smb share as part of the local filesystem using the fstab in linux. Then you can refer to it like a local drive.

Comment: No.. I don't want to mount it. I want to use the smb url with credential. Isn't it possible without mounting.

Comment: you can mount with credential? Is there a reason you dont want to mount?

Comment: I don' want to mount it each time. If the folders are changed, then I need to mount it again. I don't want to mount all the shared folders.